# PHP Script colorization with Monaco editor without PHP opening tag

Tags: php, monaco-editor

I want to use the monaco editor for PHP scripts.

Due to my program logic, I don't need the opening tag

Is there a way to use the regular PHP colorization without adding the opening tag to the editor value?

PS: I'm using the monaco editor via web component in Polymer: https://github.com/PolymerVis/monaco-editor
However, if the web component needs some adjustments, I wouldn't mind adding them. So, if you know how to drop the opening tag in the "regular" monaco case, I will find out how to forward that to the web component.

Comment: I would change your program logic rather than hack what you want

Comment: In my program logic, the user should usually only add one or two lines of PHP code with the logic providing the rest. Adding the opening tag would bloat the intended thin editor, so it would be really nice to avoid it.

Comment: the user is sending php code? this sounds hell of a insecure